# what are device APIs

Tags: terminology

Till now I thought device APIs are Hardware Abstraction Layer APIs, but when I searched in google, got a totally different definition (below).

"Definition - What does Device API (DAP) mean?

A device API is an application programming interface (API) that allows developers to create Web applications that interact with device hardware. A device API basically allows end users to use their hardware to interact with the Web in ways beyond what is allowed by standard Web browsers."

So what are device APIs?

Answer (score 0):

API's are a controlled way for third parties to interface with software. For example Facebook provides a set of API's which will allow third party developers to interface with Facebook in a manner that Facebook wants. These are generally protected method calls and class implementations that protect how the third party interacts with the provided software.  As an example, the Facebook API will control how a user uses the login feature of Facebook. So if I'm building a mobile app that wants to leverage the Facebook login, I use the Facebook API, which allows me to access the Facebook servers and databases in a manner they see fit.